# Default value for maxtenuringthreshold flag for CMS garbage collector?

Tags: garbage-collection

What is the default value for maxtenuringthreshold flag for concurrent mark sweep garbage collector ?

Is it 4 or 15 ?

Answer (score 0):

Effective configuration flags can be obtained via `java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`

Note that setting some flags can affect other flags, that's why you have to enable CMS to get the CMS-specific defaults.

Comment: It is enabled , i guess maxtenuringthreshold is implicitly being used by CMS GC tuning . So just want to confirm what is the implicit value it uses .  G1 has default as 15 but not sure with this flag value for CMS

Answer (score 0):

Default value is **6** for Java 8

> -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=threshold
>   The largest value is 15. The default value is 15 for the parallel (throughput) collector, and 6 for the CMS collector.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABFAFAE

and **4** for Java <7

> The current largest value is 15. The default value is 15 for the parallel collector and is 4 for CMS.

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/vmoptions-jsp.html#DebuggingOptions